# How to convert binary input into utf-16 characters on bash

Tags: bash, conversion, pipe, utf-8

I have bunch of bytes that has random bits in order and some of them 9 and 10. I can convert the 8 bit binary data into characters with a perl script like below.

```
perl -lape '$_=pack"(B8)*",@F'
```

But I need to convert it into utf-16 characters and need a similar way as shown. How may I do that?

PS: I don't have any issue about using utf-16 characters on bash.

Comment: Can you show a `xxd` dump of the input and the expected output?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not show xxd dump because it's a binary string. and I need to get their ASCII values. for example 100000101 to ą

Comment: Why is 100000101 ą in UTF-16?

Comment: Because it's 9 bit. Do I know wrong? If so I'll maintain the title.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to convert from a codepoint to UTF-16. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6240055/1030675

Comment: Thank you. That's a good thread which describes the problem. However I could not find an information about packing 9bit binary values into ASCII or something. Will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perl, you can use [oct](http://p3rl.org/oct) to convert a binary number to decimal. Then, use [chr](http://p3rl.org/chr) to convert from a codepoint to a character. [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode) can than encode the character into UTF-16.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Encode;

my $in = '100000101';
my $codepoint = oct "0b$in";
print encode('UTF-16', chr $codepoint);
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
printf 100000101 | perl -MEncode -wne 'print encode("UTF-16", chr oct "0b$_")'
```